# Why I obtain this WP_Query strange behavior trying to select posts having a specific tag?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have the following problem with **featured tag posts**

I have a page of a website in wich I want to show only the posts that have setted a specific tag (using the loop).

So in this page I have put this loop code:

```
<header class="header-sezione">
    <?php
        echo"<h1>IN EVIDENZA:</h1>";

            $featured = new WP_Query('tag=featured');

            if ($featured->have_posts()) : 
                while ($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();
                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part('content', get_post_format());

            endwhile;
            //wp_reset_postdata();
            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part('content', 'none');

            endif;
    ?>
</header>
```

In theory this loop should show only the post having the **featured** tag set but it works partialy because it corrctly displays all the posts having the **featured** tag set but when there is a single post it shows it also when this post doesn't have the  **featured** tag set.

I can't understand why it happens because I am specifying that have to select only the featured tag by this query:

```
$featured = new WP_Query('tag=featured');
```

What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.

The problem was not with the query but it was caused by the presence of this line:

```
get_template_part('content', 'none');
```

If I delete it it work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Insert

> wp_reset_query();

and

> wp_reset_postdata();

at the end of the loop. This will reset the query.

Comment: where exactly I have to put these? can you give me a code snippet?

Comment: At the end of the loop; please find [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) more information.

Answer (score 0):

For extra filter you can use like this argument
$cat_posts = new WP_Query("showposts=2&tag=featured&orderby=date&order=DESC");

```
<?php 
    $cat_posts = new WP_Query("tag=featured"); 
  while ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ){
                    $cat_posts->the_post(); ?>   
                    <div class="btext1">
                     <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                     <h4><?php echo the_time('F j, Y'); ?> </h4>
                     <p><?php echo get_the_content(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">more »</a></p>
                   </div>

   <?php   }  ?>
```